# In active admin is it possible to create a dynamic confirm message to a batch action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin, formtastic

ActiveAdmin's page says you can have a dynamic form by passing a proc http://activeadmin.info/docs/9-batch-actions.html ... I want to use a dynamic confirm message. any ideas?

For example... if i'd like to list all the selected ids in my confirm message-- 
or more specifically i'd like to list a column of the selected active record object.

Comment: for example? define "dynamic confirm message"

Comment: Those dialogs are created with JavaScript, so you can't insert dynamic content (e.g. the selected rows) into the confirmation message via a `proc` or `lambda`.